# Maintaining 3rd party reference in .NET class library

Tags: .net, payflowpro

With the recent TLS1.2 requirements by PayPal we're forced to make some updates we weren't planning on doing so quickly.

Our current process uses VB6 ActiveX dlls registered on our servers as COM objects. They handle all of the payment processing and interaction with PayPal's PayFlow Pro gateway. They use the Payflow Pro component directly and we use these components in legacy Classic ASP (Active Server Pages) applications (not sure that is relevant to the issue though).

I have to rewrite them in .NET 4.6.1 and they must continue being registered as COM objects on our servers to prevent having to make any application end changes at this time.

I can build the .NET project, set is as COM-visible, copy the DLL class to each server, and register it on each applicable server. I can then create an instance of these objects and classes in my applications without issue.

But as soon my class library needs to reference a 3rd party component I have an issue.

Create my project, add reference to 3rd party component, build my project. I see in my BIN directory my DLL which I need to move to each server and register to make it COM visible. But building my project also puts a copy of the 3rd party DLLs in my BIN folder.

When I create an instance of my component in my applications and call code that uses the 3rd party reference I get the error "Could not load file or assembly 'Payflow_dotNET, Version=4.3.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=14aa1e8d77f2a97c' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified."

Any reference I add that uses core framework libraries continue working fine.

So how to I make these 3rd party DLLs which are added to my project as a reference continue to be available to my COM class library when registered on our servers (using REGASM). It works fine when my project is published as an application, but when used as a COM class library, I lose the ability to interact with the 3rd party component.

Comment: It is a long shot, but have you tried to set "copy local" to false in the referenced assembly properties? (select it and press F4)

Comment: @heringer just tried and received the same error

Comment: Side note, I can see the Payflow_dotNET.dll file is registered on the server. I can create an instance of this in my classic ASP applications. I'm just not sure how to access it without creating a direct reference in my .NET project